# Remove all string after .txt

Tags: regex, csv

I have a csv file column contains:

> The_Guardian2017-01-30_17-44_part199.pdf.txt_00076___1486548173000___4982
>   The_Guardian2017-01-30_17-44_part286.pdf.txt_000D7___1486548174948___5316
>   The_Guardian2017-01-30_17-44_part343.pdf.txt_00117___1486548176288___9737

............

I want to remove all the string after

> .txt

to looks like this:

> The_Guardian2017-01-30_17-44_part199.pdf.txt

any suggestions?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tMwPH5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find:**

```
^(.*?\.txt).*$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

The above solution would work out of the box in Notepad++ and other similar editors.  The regex matches and captures everything up until the *first* `.txt`, ignoring everything which follows.

## Demo here

Answer (score 0):

Using Python for the same.

```
import re

text = "The_Guardian2017-01-30_17-44_part199.pdf.txt_00076___1486548173000___4982"

#Method 1
print(text.split('_0')[0])

#Method 2
print(text[:-29])

#Method 3
m = re.match('^(.*?\.txt)',text)
print(m.group(1))
```